# Overheat alert warning on CPU through Serial port

Tags: serial-port, overclocking

Is there any way to make an external alarm go off if your CPU reaches a certain temperature using your serial port?  I over-clocked my processor and I get warnings if it reaches a certain temperature, but that would only be useful if I am on my computer.

Comment: I suppose so, but serial port? where does serial port come into it?

Comment: If you have overclocked your CPU and its overheating then your overclock is unstable.  What you want is not possible.